# How to handle the search result of google map in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps

I found many sample about it.
But they are all using geocoding likes

http://maps.google.co.kr/maps/geo?q=대성학원&output=json

I want a result that the original google map returns

like
http://maps.google.co.kr?q=대성학원&output=json

The question is how to handle the output data??

I want to take the informations in there just like the address infos and location info.

Could anyone helps me out?? Thanks a lot~~